# Can a Spring MVC @Bean inspect the HTTP Request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-bean

I have a scenario where HTTP requests are received by a Spring application with a custom ContentType and a JSON payload.  A piece of the payload is a key used in a service locator call.

Payload:

```js
{ "service_id": "ServiceA" }
```

I'd like to use a `@RequestScope`'d Spring `@Bean` to inspect the request and return / inject the correct service.

Something like:

```java
@Configuration
public class ServiceLocatorConfig {

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public SomeService serviceByKey(WebRequest request, Map<String, SomeService> services) {

        // This is where I need a hand -- how would I get the request body?
        String serviceId = readServiceIdFromRequestBody(request);
        return services[key];
    }

}
```

So far I'm receiving the request in my `@Bean`, but haven't had any success getting the request body.  The closest I've gotten is by blindly experimenting with `ContentCachingRequestWrapper`, but I've always received `null` when calling `.getContentAsByteArray()`.  It also sounds as though it requires a form-encoded body -- so the custom content type (which can't be modified in this case) may be causing more trouble.

How can a Spring Bean inspect a HTTP request?

Comment: What about if your write your own `HttpServletRequestWrapper` for your content-type similar to `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` and introduce it as the first filter and then you should have access to the content in `ServiceLocatorConfig`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you need you can make use of a `WebFilter` which will work as an interceptor for incoming requests before it reaches your `services`, it will have access the json payload and you can read the incoming parameter and call the appropriate component to handle the request.

**Your `WebFilter` class will look similar to this one (on this example we are intercepting requests to '/rest/*':**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;


@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/rest/*")
public class DoSomethingInterceptor implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        //Parse the json from request
        String jsonPayload = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
        IncomingRequest jsonRequest = mapper.readValue(jsonPayload, IncomingRequest.class);
        
        //Read the service parameter
        String serviceClass = jsonRequest.getServiceClass();
        
        //Map the incoming service to your service class
        Class<MyService> myServiceClass = ServiceType.get(serviceClass);
        
        //Get the bean from Spring context
        DoSomething bean =
                (DoSomething) WebApplicationContextUtils.
                        getRequiredWebApplicationContext(filterConfig.getServletContext()).
                        getBean(myServiceClass);
        
        //Call the method in the service
        String resultFromService = bean.doSomething();
        
        //Finally you will copy the result from service to the http response
        response.getOutputStream().write(resultFromService);
        return;
    }
}
```

**Also remember to register your WebFilter on Spring, for SpringBoot app it can be done like in below example:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public FilterRegistrationBean registerFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistration.setFilter(new DoSomethingInterceptor());
        List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
        urlPatterns.add("/rest/*");
        filterRegistration.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
        return filterRegistration;
    }
```